# How to return object instead of method return value?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that I'm trying to condense:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
urlParams.set('order', 'dates');
window.location.search = urlParams;
```

My first attempt was to write:

```js
window.location.search = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).set('order', 'dates');
```

But this just redirects me to `/?undefined`

After some digging I understood that this does not return the modified URLSearchParams object, but just the return value of the `URLSearchParams.set()` method which is always `undefined`.

What options to I have to make this code as short as possible, to inline it into an HTML elements `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Some languages have cascade operators, which would allow you to do e.g. 

window.location.search = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search))..set('order', 'dates');

notice the two dots before "set". This returns the params but also modifies them in one line.
Js does NOT however, so you are forced to write multiple lines of code, or come up with a hack solution. 
Just extract a function, and reuse it where needed. No need to overthink it

Comment: The question really is why you would want to do this. In best case you'll end up with a one-liner that no one is going to be able to immediately comprehend when first seeing it, therefore making an easy thing hard, which is the opposite of what good, maintainable good should do. Just use a method and re-use that if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code cannot be compressed (according to my perspective). If anyone gets any way to compress it, I would be happy that someone has put their time and shown up to answer the question. Also, inform me too in the comments.

But this all can be squished into one (ugly) line:

```js
window.location.search = (() => {let u = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);u.set('order', 'dates'); return u;})();
```

Not completely sure, but this should work. Inform me if it works or not :)

Answer (score 0):

The code works well without any compression.

I wouldn't recommend to minify it manually. I guess some bundlers could compress JS inside html like in `onclick` attributes.

```html
<button onclick="const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); params.set('order', 'dates'); window.location.search = params;">Navigate</button>
```

A minified version could be:

```html
<button onclick="l=location;p=new URLSearchParams(l.search);p.set('order','dates');l.search=p">Navigate</button>
```